# Connect multiple database in select Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three database now I want to retrieve data from 2 tables in different database.

Like wise `ledger` table in `master` database, `book` table in `general` database.

So first I wrote query like this

```
 select * 
 from master.ledger, general.book
```

It show an error.

> Could not find file in C:\Documents and Settings\MyDocuments...

Then, I wrote a query like this

```
select * 
from ledger, book IN 'C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\2014\fa.mdb', 
'C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\2014\general.mdb'
```

It also show an error

> 'Syntax Error in From Clause'

But If I use single database like

```
select * 
from ledger IN 'C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\2014\fa.mdb';
```

it works correctly. How can I connect multiple database in a select query?

Comment: Commas will not help. Why not just link the tables?

Comment: See http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked tables are the easiest way, but you can also do it like this:

```
SELECT TblA.*, TblB.* FROM [;DATABASE='C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\2014\fa.mdb'].Master AS tblA
INNER JOIN [;DATABASE='C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\2014\general.mdb'.[General] AS TblB
ON tblA.SomeField=tblB.SomeField
```

Of course this assumes you have a common field between the two.

Comment: Agreed - and I indicated that linked tables are easiest.

Comment: This is needed where linked table is not possible. The DB paths going to change each time, we can pickup dynamically or thr' code.